# How to combine similar elements in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame consisting of

```
Lancaster001A    76
Lancaster001B    35
Lancaster002A    46
Lancaster002D     9
....             ...
```

I'd like to consolidate the dataframe into this

```
Lancaster001    111
Lancaster002     55
```

And so remove the smaller categorising. I couldn't find a way to do with merge, is there a general function that can be used using similarity?

Comment: What is the structure of your data? Is there only ever one character after the 001? A `dput()` of some of your data would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using [a regex](https://regex101.com/r/pO7gQ7/1) to remove all characters after three numeric characters:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "Lancaster001A    76
                 Lancaster001B    35
                 Lancaster002A    46
                 Lancaster002D     9")

setNames(aggregate(V2 ~ gsub("(?<=\\d{3}).*", "", V1, perl = TRUE), 
                   DF, FUN = sum), 
         c("V1", "V2"))
#            V1  V2
#1 Lancaster001 111
#2 Lancaster002  55
```

It would be trivial to use data.table if the aggregation is too slow on a large dataset.

Adjust the regex as needed if the structure of your data is different.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume these names for your columns, and let's assume the 'smaller categorising' means one letter at the end.

```
id               value
Lancaster001A    76
Lancaster001B    35
Lancaster002A    46
Lancaster002D     9
....             ...
```

I use dplyr for everything. [Install dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/README.html), make sure your column names are correct, and then try:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  mutate(id = substr(id, 1, nchar(id)-1) %>% # removes last character
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(value))
```

Answer (score 2):

*Edit:* An even simpler data.table solution from @Arun's helpful tip:

```
library(data.table)
dt[, list(sum=sum(value)), by = substr(as.character(id),1,nchar(as.character(id)) - 1)]

             id sum
1: Lancaster001 111
2: Lancaster002  55
```

Comment: You can create the grouping column on the fly by providing expressions in `by`, i.e., `by = .(id = substr(...))`. See section 2d under Introduction to data.table vignette [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: I tried that initially, but got an error aggregating, although this works `dt[, list(sum=sum(value)), by = substr(as.character(id),1,nchar(as.character(id)) - 1)]` so I don't really know what happened...anyway thanks for the helpful tip!

Comment: hm.. strange. This works for me on v1.9.7 (devel): `dt[, .(sum=sum(value)), by = .(id=substr(as.character(id),1,nchar(as.character(id)) - 1))]`. Perhaps an issue with `v1.9.6` (or whatever version you're on) that has been fixed..

Comment: I just checked, it was definitely something on my end. Your code works perfect - sorry about the confusion.